# Specify top-left corner position for QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, mouse, qmenu

I have QPoint **pos** after clicking mouse and what to show at this point QMenu. But I what menu to appear that this **pos** will be left top corner of QMenu. And

```
menu.exec(pos);
```

shows menu such that **pos** is it's left edge middle point

Comment: maybe OS handle this left right corner ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **mapToGlobal** like this:

```
//menu.exec(pos);
menu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
```

Comment: Yes, I do so, 'cos I have widgets in widgets. Is seems that it's possible to do what I what only by changing pos coordinates.